# Rails: Bug in Logic Related to Rails Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where Users receive Points for Games.  I have a bug in my code which is meant to subtotal and rank each Users' Points by Game_Type for the past week (in a GameTypeRank table).  This works fine if the User has Points for the past week, however, it doesn't work correctly if the User has no Points for the past week.  If the User has no Points, they should be updated in the GameTypeRank with 0 points otherwise, they retain their last ranking until updated (and the ranks are incorrect).

```
# user.rb:
def self.update_game_type_weekly_rank
  @game_types = GameType.all
  @game_types.each do |game_type|

  # this query is where the bug is since it is possible a User has no Points  
  @user_with_points = Point.where("game_type_id = ? and created_at >= ?", game_type.id, 1.week.ago).sum(:points, :group => :user_id, :order => 'sum(points) desc')
    rank = point_counter = 0

    @user_with_points.each do |user_id, points|
      @game_type_rank = GameTypeRank.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_game_type_id(user_id, game_type.id)
      if points != point_counter
        point_counter = points
        rank += 1
      end
      @game_type_rank.weekly_rank = rank
      @game_type_rank.weekly_points = points
      @game_type_rank.save
    end
  end
end

# Models

# game_type_rank.rb
# fields - user_id, game_type_id, weekly_points, weekly_rank
belongs_to :game_type
belongs_to :user

# point.rb
# fields - user_id, points, game_type_id
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :game_type
belongs_to :user
```

I could create a method that runs weekly and creates Point records (with Point.points = 0) for each User that didn't have any for the week, but that is a poor solution.

I could also maybe initialize the `weekly_points` and `weekly_rank` for each GameTypeRank record at the beginning of the method, but that seems inefficient to me (and I'm not sure of the best way to do this).

```
# Sample Data
Points
|user_id|points|game_type_id|created_at
|1      |   10 |           1|2013-05-07
|1      |   10 |           2|2013-05-07
|2      |   20 |           2|2012-12-31 
|1      |   5  |           2|2012-12-31 

before weekly_update - Game_Type_Ranks 
|user_id |game_type_id | weekly_points | weekly_rank|
|1       |2            |5              |2
|2       |2            |20             |1

after weekly_update - Game_Type_Ranks 
|user_id |game_type_id | weekly_points | weekly_rank|
|1       |1            |10             |1
|1       |2            |10             |1
|2       |2            |20             |1

what should happen after weekly_update - Game_Type_Ranks
|user_id |game_type_id | weekly_points | weekly_rank|
|1       |1            |10             |1
|1       |2            |10             |1
|2       |2            |0              |2   <== update for user_id 2
```

Comment: Some sample input data along with expected and actual output would be useful.

Comment: I added some sample data, thank you

Comment: Is it necessary for the users that were not active in the current week to have a 0 weekly points. Could we just leave them out?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you don't have access to users who have an existing rank but were not active for the current week in `@user_with_points` for the given `GameType`.

Why not leave this as is but utilize the `updated_at` timestamp. When making a call to your `GameTypeRank` object just pull the ones that were updated in the past week.

```
# some controller
GameTypeRank.where("id = ? and updated_at >= ?", id, 1.week.ago)
```

However with this you lose the ability to set the old raked users weekly_points to 0.

An alternative is to loop through all users that have points for the given GameType regardless of time, like so:

```
# user.rb:
def self.update_game_type_weekly_rank
  @game_types = GameType.all
  @game_types.each do |game_type|

    @user_with_points = Point.where("game_type_id = ?", game_type.id).sum(:points, :group => :user_id, :order => 'sum(points) desc')
      rank = point_counter = 0
      @user_with_points.each do |user_id, points|
        @game_type_rank = GameTypeRank.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_game_type_id(user_id, game_type.id)
        if points != point_counter
          point_counter = points
          rank += 1
        end
        @game_type_rank.weekly_rank = rank
        @game_type_rank.weekly_points = points
        @game_type_rank.save
      end
    end

  end
end
```

After this your table should be the way you want it. Now this comes at a cost as you probably realize. Maybe you could have some sort of cut off from inactivity. Say for example 6 months.

```
# users.rb
....
@user_with_points = Point.where("game_type_id = ? and created_at >= ?", game_type.id, 6.months.ago).sum(:points, :group => :user_id, :order => 'sum(points) desc')
....

# some controller
GameTypeRank.where("id = ? and created_at >= ?", id, 6.months.ago)
```

Both these methods have some inefficiencies in them but it gets the job done. Plus you are probably running this method with a cron job and/or a background job so the effect on your users should be nil.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In the first option, as you pointed out, it will not rectify GameTypeRank where users had points in a prior week, but not this one.  The issue with the second option, I think, is that it will rank every user even if they did not have points for the week.  GameTypeRank actually has a rank, weekly_rank, and monthly_rank (and corresponding points fields) so I have the code for option 2 already (omitting created_at), for my overall rank, points field, but not monthly or weekly.